# Rails: Initialization Code for Redis: Where to put?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have some initialization code in Ruby that initializes a Redis database with some values. Where is the best place to put this code in the Rails application? I want this code to run right after everything is deployed. I'm using Passenger if that helps.

Comment: Run every time the application is spun up or a one time thing?

Comment: From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html  "Running Code Before Rails 
To run some code before Rails itself is loaded, simply put it above the call to require 'rails/all' in your application.rb"

Comment: @jaydel Thats not a desireable solution, since this is related to the application and the enviroment it's in the code should be placed in an initalizer.

Comment: I understand but he describes it as a task he wants to happen automatically post deployment. If you define deployment to include the starting of the server, then yes an initializer is better. But if he is talking about having it set up prior to that first start then it doesn't make much sense to put it in the initializer. I'd be less likely to go this route if it weren't about intializing the REdis key/value store. You don't put rake db:create and rake db:migrate into an initializer, right?

Comment: I want it to run everytime the app is spun up.

Comment: Then definitely in an initializer :) That link I gave offers a bunch of ways to do the thing you want to do that are all the Rails Way (in theory)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that loads stuff once per app load (initializers) belongs in `$RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers`

Comment: If this is just for production is it better to make an initializer and check if the `Rails.env` is production or would it be better to place it in `production.rb`

Comment: `production.rb` is good to but I think it's more for configuring rails.